# Prevent button jump to another position in div when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have button in a div such as image 1:

[image 1](http://www.imagesup.net/?di=10138717892213)

when i clicked on button a, it's working, but i clicked on button b, it jump to another position in div such as image 2:

[image 2](http://www.imagesup.net/?di=8138717894612)

I using javascript to add 2 button to div:

```
$("div").append('<input type="button" value="a" class="a" />').prepend('<input type="button" value="b" class="b" />');
```

i need a help

Comment: Not getting your question

Comment: And where are you adding the created div to html ?

Comment: I kind of get the question but can you include the html mark up and css declarations as well

Answer (score 2):

IMHO, You should use [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on) for `dynamically added elements` like,

```
$(document).on('click', '.b', function(){
   // you code
});
```

Comment: I think button jumped to another position, so when click to line between button a and b, it's working, but click on button b it's not working

Comment: You can use `z-index` to get your `element` on top of `other elements`